# Node.js: Are Global Vars shared between instances?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, global-variables

I have this code:

```
app.post('/pst', function(req, res) {
        var url = req.body.convo;


                myAsyncFucntion(url).then(result => { 
                    console.log('TAKE A LOOK AT THIS!');


                    //transforming array to string to pass to Buffer.from()
                    //then we remove ',' with newlines, so each index of array is a new line
                    var str = result.toString();
                    result = str.split(',').join('\r\n');


                    //clever way to send text file to client from the memory of the server
                    var fileContents = Buffer.from(result, 'ascii');
                    var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
                    readStream.end(fileContents);
                    res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
                    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                    readStream.pipe(res);

                    //garbage collecting. i don't know if it's neccessary
                    result = '';
                    str = '';

                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.render('error.ejs');
                })
});
```

This code will run an async function and serve the user some data from the memory, as a text file.
I am planing on using sockets and notifying the client that the work is done.
The client will enter a link and will download a file.

So i plan to take the local variable result and export it in a global variable.
This way, the `app.get()` will have access to it, and when the user follos that link, it will serve the file.

But a user told me that global variables are shared between instances.

Is this true? So if two (or more) users try to get their results at the same time, the global variables will be the same

for both of them?

Comment: What do you mean by "instance"?

Comment: I think he means a running instance of the node service. But, the question then is: a different user might access to data that is private to one user (?)

Comment: For example, two users visiting the web app, will be two instances.

Comment: @user1584421 Yes, there is only one runtime in which both requests will be served, and a global variable would be shared by them. You'll need to create different resources for the different users - stored in a global `Map` for example

Comment: @user1584421 Notice that if each request had its own global variables, your approach would not work either way - the `/pst` call creates a value, but then the separate request to download the file from the link could not access that if it had its own globals again. So yes, you will need to distinguish (possibly concurrent) requests by different users explicitly.

Comment: @Bergi. Thanks! So what do you suggest i use? Express session? I don't know what Map is. Could you link it?

Answer (score 6):

> Is this true?

Yes. (Well, effectively yes. The real answer is that there aren't "multiple instances" in the first place: You have one server which multiple users are making multiple requests to.)

If you want to associate data with a particular browser session, then use a [session](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=express%20session) (NPM modules to handle sessions exist for Express).

Comment: slightly misleading, the definition of 'server' and node app vs environment should be clarified. if I have two node apps running, are global props shared between both of them or is it tied to the process instance, etc.  I came searching to clarify this after another stackoverflow claimed something similar.

Answer (score -2):

This really depends on where you declare those variables.

Please read some documentation on "variable scope" in JS.

It's hard to explain it here when there are plenty of nicely written and pictured explanations out there.

If some variable is declared within the code-area that is read anew for every user-request, then this variable would be different for each user.

If you declare the variable ourside oth that part, then that content is the same for every action of your Node-application.